# Why am I getting this error: E/ERROR: The executeQuery method must return a result set.?

Tags: java, android, sql-server-2008, compiler-errors

I'm trying to connect my project with an SQL-Server database. But I always get this error E/ERROR: The `executeQuery` method must return a result set.

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String username = "un";
        String password = "pass";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip/db;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);

        Log.w("Connection","open");

        String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE" +
                "(Cliente, NomePessoa, Email, NivelSatisfacao, Nota) " +
                "VALUES ('" + informacao.getNomeCliente() + "', '" + informacao.getNome() + "', '" + informacao.getEmail() + "', '" + informacao.getSatisfacao() + "', '" + informacao.getNota() + "') ";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql); // error here
```

I tried to change `stmt.executeQuery` to `stmt.executeUpdate`, but it underlines it red, and says that the output is `int`, so it is incompatible.

Comment: You should really look into using PreparedStatement instead of Statement too.  Statement is a security flaw and is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PreparedStatement is much safer.

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    String username = "un";
    String password = "pass";

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip/db;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);

    Log.w("Connection","open");

    String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE" +
            "(Cliente, NomePessoa, Email, NivelSatisfacao, Nota) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, informacao.getNomeCliente())
        pstmt.setString(2, informacao.getNome())
        pstmt.setString(3, informacao.getEmail())
        pstmt.setString(4, informacao.getSatisfacao())
        pstmt.setString(5, informacao.getNota())

        int result = pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `executeQuery` method while querying tables in the database (when you have the `SELECT` keyword). When you want to execute SQL statements (like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and others) you should use `execute` method, as seen in [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/statement-object-example.htm).

In your case you could try:

```
Boolean rSet = stmt.execute(sql);
```

Comment: whats the diference between execute() and executeUpdate()?

Comment: Mainly the return type. The `execute` returns `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if it is an update count or there are no results. The `executeUpdate` returns either the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or `0` for SQL statements that return nothing. You can check in more detail https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html